# iOS - Error when retrieving events from last 1 year to upcoming 1 years from current date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, ekevent

This is my code to retrieve events

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startDate = [self dateByAddingYears:-1 toDate:now];
NSDate *endDate = [self dateByAddingYears:1 toDate:now];
NSArray *events = [[ECEventStoreProxy sharedInstance] eventsFrom:[startDate beginningOfDay] to:[endDate endOfDay]];

self.sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (EKEvent *event in events)
{
    // Reduce event start date to date components (year, month, day)
    NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:event.startDate];

    // If we don't yet have an array to hold the events for this day, create one
    NSMutableArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
    if (eventsOnThisDay == nil) {
        if (event.calendar.allowsContentModifications) {
            eventsOnThisDay = [NSMutableArray array];

            // Use the reduced date as dictionary key to later retrieve the event list this day
            [self.sections setObject:eventsOnThisDay forKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
        }

    }

    // Add the event to the list for this day
    [eventsOnThisDay addObject:event];
}
```

This is the error which is logged

MyApp[5173:1001] Error loading timezone data from file system. This is a serious problem. Calendar data is not guaranteed to be accurate.

If the start date is changed to current date it works perfectly...but i want to show list of past 1 year events too...

Edit 1:

```
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingYears:(NSInteger)numberOfYears toDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
// Use the user's current calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setYear:numberOfYears];

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComps toDate:inputDate options:0];
return newDate;
}
```

Comment: `dateByAddingYears:` definition? Which line exactly causes this log?

Comment: @Larme if the startdate is set to [self dateByAddingYears:0 toDate:now]; it works fine...if i set it as -1 this error occurs...

Comment: What's the code of `dateByAddingYears:`?

Comment: Seems that one of the lines of `dateByAddingYears:toDate:` is causing the issue. I couldn't reproduce it. What's your calendar identifier? Which line inside this method is causing the log?

Comment: @Larme Calendar is the default shared calendar...no idea of the line causing this issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104995/discussion-between-larme-and-hardik-amal).